# Discord.js: Remove element from an Array

Tags: javascript

```
var maps = {

'I': 'd.',
'C': 'd',
'M': 'd',
'D': 'd',
'T': 'd',
'O': 'd',
'C': 'd'

}
```

Above I have an array with different responses for a message reply set up. As in, a user in the discord text channel types C, he/she will be responded with 'd'. What I am wondering is, once a user types, for instance 'C', how can I remove that element from the array all together?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, this is an `object` and not `array`,

Comment: It's very hard to search for answers to your questions unless you first get the terminology right. As others have mentioned, this is an **object**, not an **array**. The things inside it are **properties**, not **elements**. All this should be pretty clear from any good JS tutorial. Once you know the terminology, you can search for "delete property from object javascript".

Answer (score 1):

For your info, this is an `object` and not `array`.

If you know the key that means `C`, then you can delete as below.

```js
var maps = {
    
    'I': 'd.',
    'C': 'd',
    'M': 'd',
    'D': 'd',
    'T': 'd',
    'O': 'd',
    'C': 'd'
    
    };
    
    var keyToDelete = 'C';
    
    delete maps[keyToDelete];

console.log(maps);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES7 [spread properties](http://www.2ality.com/2016/10/rest-spread-properties.html), you can write:

```
const {C, ...others} = maps;
```

and then `others` will contain the non-C properties.

When trying to "delete" something from an object or an array, as a matter of style many programmers would advise you to create a new object or array without the deleted elements or properties, as this does, rather than mutating the original object.

PS. This has nothing to do with node. It's a pure JS question.